# Lumen Authentication error - ReflectionException in Container.php line 572: Class Request does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I receive the error:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 572: Class Request does not
>   exist

See the code I'm using for my **routes.php** page.

```
$app->get('/records', ['middleware' => 'auth', function (Request $request) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    return json_encode($user);
}]);
```

I have follow the documentation on the Lumen website.  Uncommented the relevant lines with **bootstrap/app.php**

The following is my middleware code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    protected $auth;
    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
            return response()->json('unauthorized', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and the AuthServiceProvider file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
            if ($request->header('Authorization')) {
                $user = User:: where('api_token', '=', substr($request->header('Authorization'), 6))->first();
                return $user;
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

in your routes.php